# B-Splines Geometry

Tags: javascript, spline

Using the image below, I was able to understand the behavior of a spline curve for 4 points: [image: image1]
With this image I've manage to produce a 3rd degree equation and code it in javascript.

Now I'm trying to understand how to use more than 4 points.

I couldn't find an image showing a curve of 5 (or more) points. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the **De Boor Algorithm**. The following [link](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/de-Boor.html) (taken from this [course website](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/)) gives a good explanation (with figures, examples and pseudo-code) of how it works. The following figure was taken from there.

[image]

This [interactive demo](https://richardfuhr.neocities.org/BusyBCurves.html) can also give you an idea on what it looks like (note you're interested in the "Spline" demo not the "Bezier").